# Write a function to identify objects in the first array, which matches all the attribute and value pairs in the second object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key

Return type should be a array.

```js
findMatches(
    [
        {"X" : "1", "Y" : "2","Z" : "4", "P" : "5"},
        {"X" : "2", "Y" : "2","Z" : "4", "P" : "5"},
        {"X" : "1", "Y" : "2","Z" : "9", "P" : "6"}
    ],
    {"X":"1", "Y":"2"}
);
```

Should return

```json
[
    {"X" : "1", "Y" : "2","Z" : "4", "P" : "5"}, 
    {"X" : "1", "Y" : "2","Z" : "9", "P" : "6"}
]
```

Answer should be valid for any given input.

```js
function findMatches(arr ,obj) {
    return [];
}
```

```
findMatches(
    [
        {"X" : "1", "Y" : "2","Z" : "4", "P" : "5"}, 
        {"X" : "2", "Y" : "2","Z" : "4", "P" : "5"}, 
        {"X" : "1", "Y" : "2","Z" : "9", "P" : "6"}
    ], 
    {"X":"1", "Y":"2"}
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply achieve it by using [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

**Demo :**

```js
const arr = [
  {"X" : "1", "Y" : "2","Z" : "4", "P" : "5"},
  {"X" : "2", "Y" : "2","Z" : "4", "P" : "5"},
  {"X" : "1", "Y" : "2","Z" : "9", "P" : "6"}
];

const obj = {"X":"1", "Y":"2"};

function findMatches(arr, obj) {
   return arr.filter((arrayObj) => (arrayObj.X === obj.X) && (arrayObj.Y === obj.Y));
}

const res = findMatches(arr, obj);

console.log(res);
```